# Azure PaaS Databases - SQL DB vs Managed Instance

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-sql-managed-instance

I am working on both PaaS databases of Azure, i.e., Azure SQL Database and Azure SQL Managed Instance. Basic doubt is that both are 'managed' by Azure. Then why the word 'managed' is attached only to the Azure Managed Instance? Either it should be 'Azure SQL Database and Azure SQL Instance' or 'Azure SQL Managed Database and Azure SQL Managed Instance'.

The doubt may be silly. But when explaining to newbies, they get confused with the phrases 'fully managed' and 'managed instance'.

Comment: Related: *[Can "doubt" sometimes mean "question"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/can-doubt-sometimes-mean-question)*

Answer (score 1):

Marketing people pick the names.  Don’t read too much into it.  They are both “managed”.

Comment: I've a question related to Azure SQL posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72399479/1232087). It seems it has no solid solution. But I was wondering if there is a work around to resolve the issue.