# Apache Spark not importing UTF-16 data file to SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, apache-spark, azure-sql-database

I am using using `Apache Spark connector` to import data from data files to `Azure SQL Server`. It works fine for utf-8 files. But for `UTF-16` files I am getting the following error despite the fact that columns and their total numbers is exactly the same in both Spark Dataframe and destination SQL Server table

**Error**:

> ERROR: java.sql.SQLException: Spark Dataframe and SQL Server table have differing numbers of columns

**Question**: What I may be doing wrong and how can we resolve the issue? I've tried various suggestions from online [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=apache%20spark%20utf-16%20encoding&rlz=1C1GCEU_enUS998US998&oq=apa&aqs=chrome.0.69i59l2j69i57j69i59j0i433i512l2j0i131i433i457i512j0i402l2j0i433i512.2596j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) but still no luck.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df = spark.read.option("multiline","true").option("encoding", "UTF-16").csv("abfss://myAzureContainer@myGen2StorageAccount.dfs.core.windows.net/Test/myUTF16File.txt", escape="\"", header="true", inferSchema="true")

server_name = "jdbc:sqlserver://{SERVER_ADDR}"
database_name = "database_name"
url = server_name + ";" + "databaseName=" + database_name + ";"

table_name = "MySQLTable"
username = "username"
password = "myPassword"

try:
  df.write \
    .format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark") \
    .mode("overwrite") \
    .option("url", url) \
    .option("dbtable", table_name) \
    .option("user", username) \
    .option("password", password) \
    .save()
except ValueError as error :
    print("Connector write failed", error)
```

**UPDATE**: When open in `Notepad++` it shows its encoding as follows. I tried the `option("encoding", "UTF-16LE")` in the above code, as well. But still the same error:

[image]

Comment: Has the file has been manipulated in Microsoft Excel in any way, shape or form? Check its content in a text editor. Excel has a nasty habit of outputting blank columns and rows to delimited files after columns and/or rows have been deleted in a worksheet.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning No the file has never been fed to Excel. I just added an **UPDATE** section where it shows file's encoding.

Comment: Hi, can you try this, Use the flatMap to decode and then read it.
For reference, please check it [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-32965).

Comment: The error says nothing about Unicode. Python 3 strings are UTF8 already, so the dataframe data is UTF8 already. The error complains about the number of columns. Most likely, the CSV file was read using the wrong field delimiter. What does `myUTF16File.txt` contain?

Answer (score 0):

Check the below information from [CSV DataSource can detect encoding of input files automatically](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-migration-guide.html#data-sources).

- In 2.4 version and before that, CSV datasource can automatically  detect the input files if we have BOM at the starting.
- And CSV datasource can identify the **UTF-8, UTF-16BE, UTF-16LE, UTF-32BE and UTF-32LE** in the `multi-line` mode by setting it to `true`.
- From Spark 3.O CSV datasource reads the input files in encoding specified via the CSV option  `encoding`  which has the default value of UTF-8.
- So, if the file encoding doesn’t match to the encoding specified via the CSV option, Spark loads the file incorrectly.
- To solve this issue, we have to set correct encoding through the CSV option  `encoding`  or set the option to  `null`  encoding auto-detection as in Spark versions before 3.0.

And make sure to re-check the proper escape sequence by using `sep` or `delimiter`.

if you are using python then try to use the `flatMap` to decode and then `read` it.

**Reference:** [pyspark reading csv files with utf_16le encoding](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-32965).